# How do I export one Cognito Form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I can't seem to find the option to download one Cognito Form at a time anymore now that this new feature has been implemented. I have done "Actions" > "Export" > "Selection" but it only provides me an Excel spreadsheet of who submitted the Cognito Form.

Please let me know how to Export one Cognito Form at a time with all the information that was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can select to export one entry by searching, or sorting your entries so only the entry that you want to export is displayed. You can then select the 'Export' option to export the entry to Excel.

You can also create a PDF for the entry by using either of the two default templates under 'Create Document'. The first default template will be the entry details as it shows on the Entries page, the second will show the fields around the answers.